# Filter and Fill visible cells with formula VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering if there is a way of going through a filter list. for each filtered list I will perform a formula. i.e

```
Company Name             Invoice Number              Voucher Number
CompanyA                 000001                      TX100
CompanyA                 000001                      //copy what's on top
CompanyA                 000001                     //copy what's on top
CompanyB                 000002
CompanyB                 000002
CompanyC                 000003                     TY909
CompanyC                 000003                     //copy what's on top
```

Basically I need to filter the column company name(Range A filter) as you can notice for each company name some rows of voucher rows values are missing I just need to fill it with the same voucher number so it'll be like ...

```
Company Name             Invoice Number              Voucher Number
    CompanyA                 000001                      TX100
    CompanyA                 000001                      TX100
    CompanyA                 000001                      TX100
    CompanyB                 000002
    CompanyB                 000002
    CompanyC                 000003                     TY909
    CompanyC                 000003                     TY909
```

I want output to be like that
notice I don't need to fill for those that doesn't have voucher number i.e CompanyB

I've tried this code without filtering each company ...

```
Range("V2:V" & xRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=IF(J2<>"""",J2,IF(V1="""","""",V1))"
Range("V2:V" & xRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = Range("V2:V" & xRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
Range("V1:V" & xRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
Range("J1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

the dilemma is it copies everything on top of if so it'll be like

```
Company Name             Invoice Number              Voucher Number
    CompanyA                 000001                      TX100
    CompanyA                 000001                      TX100
    CompanyA                 000001                      TX100
    CompanyB                 000002                      TX100
    CompanyB                 000002                      TX100
    CompanyC                 000003                     TY909
    CompanyC                 000003                     TY909
```

which is wrong. any help? or improvements.

**Update:**
I've tried using filter

```
Sub try()
Dim currRng As Range, dataRng As Range, currCell As Range
Dim xRow As Long
xRow = Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
With ActiveSheet
        Set currRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
        Set dataRng = .Range("V2:V" & xRow)
       ' Range("AF:XFD").Delete
        With .UsedRange
            With .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count)
                With .Resize(currRng.rows.Count)
                    .Value = currRng.Value
                    .RemoveDuplicates Array(1), Header:=xlYes
                    For Each currCell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                        currRng.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=currCell.Value
                        If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, currRng) - 1 > 0 Then
                            dataRng.Value = Range("I2").Value
                            dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula = "=IF(I2<>"""",I2,IF(V2="""","""",V2))"
                            dataRng.Value = dataRng.Value
                            dataRng.Copy Destination:=Range("I2")
                            dataRng.ClearContents
                        End If
                       Next currCell
                    .ClearContents
                End With
            End With
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

range("V:V") is where I'm storing/dumping my formula, Range("I:I") is the column range where Voucher number is stored, but I still get no result or null. I need to filter every company and from that company if the first row result of that company is null make it all null (say in CompanyB in my sample) and if it does have a value (like my sample ng CompanyA and CompanyC) fill those down.

Comment: I believe the problem is you are copying visible cells only, and want them to be pasted into visible cells as well, is this correct?

Comment: hi @Davesexcel yes! That's why I want to filter first the company column so if voucher number is null it has to stay null. the problem with the formula I have is it copies everything on top of it if it's null. so basically CompanyB copies the voucher number of CompanyA since it has value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon trying several times I've come up with this code...

```
Sub voucher_num()
Dim cell As Range, currRng As Range, dataRng As Range, currCell As Range, destRng As Range
Dim xRow As Long
xRow = Cells(rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
With ActiveSheet
        Set currRng = .Range("A1", .Cells(.rows.Count, "").End(xlUp)) 'column range of my filter
        Set dataRng = .Range("V2:V" & xRow) 'range of column I'm dumping my formula
        Set destRng = .Range("I2:I" & xRow) 'storing again the values I've come up with from the formula

        With .UsedRange
            With .Resize(1, 1).Offset(, .Columns.Count)
                With .Resize(currRng.rows.Count)
                    .Value = currRng.Value
                    '.RemoveDuplicates Array(1), Header:=xlYes
                For Each currCell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

                currRng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=currCell.Value

                If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, currRng) - 1 > 0 Then
                    dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = destRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
                    dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FillDown
                    dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value
                    dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=destRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                    dataRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
                End If

        Next currCell
    .ClearContents
            End With
        End With
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
End Sub
```

This takes quite your time, I haven't come up with a better/faster approach but this is doing what I want.

Answer (score 3):

edited after OP's clarifications about data placement:

you may use this

```
Range("V2:V" & xRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Formula =IF(I2<>"""",I2,IF(A2<>A1,"""",IF(U1="""","""",U1)))
```

Comment: hi @user3598756 I suppose that is inserted in for each in filtered cell? I'm quite loss now :/

Comment: you can insert it without filtering. and thus remove the `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` part

Comment: @Anne, did you get through it?

Comment: hi @user3598756 let me try that :)

Comment: ahm I'm sorry @user3598756 but that was my problem before. It aso copies data that is not supposed to be just like in my sample CompanyA and CompanyB

Comment: I don't get you. I tested it with not filtered data data as per your first posted ones and I came to data as per your 2nd posted ones. I assumed that "Company Name" column is column "H", "Voucher Number" column is column "J" and resulting "Voucher Number" column is column "V"

Comment: hi @user3598756  tried your code turns out it's null

Comment: _"turns out it's null"_ isn't a helpful description at all! First off, did my description of what each data is supposed to be complying with your actual data layout?

Comment: hi @user3598756 first of all thank you for your time and reaching out help. I did put your code. what I do have in my raw file is like this
`CompanyA                                    _null_

CompanyA                                    _null_
CompanyB                                    TX7878
CompanyB                                   _null_`
so I guess Company B copied the null. which is on top

Comment: with your data as per your last comment placed in columns "H" (Company Name) and "J" (Voucher Number) my formula fills corresponding columns "V" cells with "nothing" for "company a" and "TX7878 " for "company b". which I got is desired result, isn't it?

Comment: may be you te your time to check what I assumed _" I assumed that "Company Name" column is column "H", "Voucher Number" column is column "J" and resulting "Voucher Number" column is column "V"_

Comment: oh I'm sorry Company Name is in Column A , voucher Number is in Column I and Column V is my dumping/storing column for formula that I will also just copy back to column I and clear column V once finished to a certain Company filter

Comment: Thanks for your great support @user3598756 I'm trying it now without looping `Range("V2:V" & xRow).Formula =IF(I2<>"""",I2,IF(A2<>A1,"""",IF(U1="""","""",U1)))`

Comment: that formula needs a loop since it has `xRow` last row index variable! If you want to test it outside a loop try `Range("V2:V100").Formula =IF(I2<>"""",I2,IF(A2<>A1,"""",IF(U1="""","""",U1)))`, where I assumed that data to be processed are from row 2 to 100, if not change 100 to your actual needs. and let me know

Comment: hi @user3598756 tried it but still not getting the result (not copying) :(

Comment: ws.Range("BG4:BG" & Lst_row).SpecialCells(12).Formula ="=1+1"

Answer (score 0):

The below code helps to Copy and paste the formulas in visible cells only.  Its working fine for me.  You can put any other formulas too.

```
    Dim Xrow As Long, WS As Worksheet, dng As Range
    Xrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With ActiveSheet
        Set WS = ActiveSheet
        Set dng = .Range("H1:H" & Xrow)
        WS.Range("A1:BD1" & Xrow).AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="Sheets"
        Range("H1").Select
        dng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).FormulaR1C1 = "=RC[1]"
    End With

    'To remove Autofilter
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

    'To copy and paste special values for columns use the below
    Columns.EntireColumn("H").Copy
    Columns.EntireColumn("H").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```